# How add Build Phases Run Script Phase in Ionic Appflow

Tags: ionic-framework, salesforce, ionic-appflow

I need to run a native Xcode build script during the iOS build in Ionic Appflow.

For e.g I am using cordova-plugin-salesforce-snapins plugin and as per their documentation we need to run these scripts:

```
select Build Phases
create Run script
paste this line of code $PODS_ROOT/ServiceSDK/Frameworks/ServiceCore.framework/prepare-framework
```

It is possible in Xcode but there is no such way to achieve this in ionic Appflow.

Please help me to configure this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the npm plugin [`cordova-node-xcode`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode), which allows you to write the build phase to the generated Xcode project file. Add `"xcode": "^3.0.1"` to your devDependencies in package.json.

Call a .js script `AddBuildScript.js` from a Cordova "after_build" hook in your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <hook src="AddBuildScript.js" type="after_build" />
```

Script `AddBuildScript.js`:

```
var xcode = require('xcode'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    projectPath = 'platforms/ios/MyProj.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj',
    proj = xcode.project(projectPath);

proj.parse(function (err) {
        var scriptName = 'My Script';
        var buildPhases = proj.getPBXObject('PBXShellScriptBuildPhase');
        if (JSON.stringify(buildPhases).match(scriptName)) {
            console.log('Xcode project not updated - ' + scriptName + ' already exists')
        } else {
            var options = {shellPath: '/bin/sh', shellScript: '$PODS_ROOT/ServiceSDK/Frameworks/ServiceCore.framework/prepare-framework'};
            proj.addBuildPhase([], 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase', scriptName, proj.getFirstTarget().uuid, options);
           
            fs.writeFileSync(projectPath, proj.writeSync());
            console.log('Xcode project updated - added ' + scriptName);
        }
});
```